# Mouse setting and desktop not appearing in Ubuntu setting

Tags: unity, 22.04, mouse

I have a problem with desktop and mouse. The desktop icon is not appearing. Also I can't add a shortcut on it, but I can show the icon from files desktop. about the mouse don't appear create files and properties.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop Issue]

Mouse:

[image: Mouse Issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I remove Ubuntu desktop and reinstall it again the command is

to install it

sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop

to remove it

sudo apt remove ubuntu-gnome-desktop gnome-shell